# How to pass flags to nvcc in google colab?

Tags: jupyter-notebook, cuda, google-colaboratory, nvcc, compiler-flags

I want to use `__device__` lambda but it said that I need to pass the flag '--expt-extended-lambda'.

I use this environment in colab.

```
!wget https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/9.2/Prod/local_installers/cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-9-2- 
local_9.2.88-1_amd64 -O cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-9-2-local_9.2.88-1_amd64.deb
!dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1604-9-2-local_9.2.88-1_amd64.deb
!apt-key add /var/cuda-repo-9-2-local/7fa2af80.pub
!apt-get update
!apt-get install cuda-9.2
!nvcc --version

!pip install git+git://github.com/andreinechaev/nvcc4jupyter.git
%load_ext nvcc_plugin
```

And I write codes like this

```
%%cu
int main() {}
```

I have no idea to pass the flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My reading of the [relevant code](https://github.com/andreinechaev/nvcc4jupyter/blob/master/v2/v2.py) suggests that you can't. There appears to be no support for passing additional arguments to nvcc via that plugin.

You would need to fork and modify the plugin to taste or petition the authors of the plugin to do the same if you don't understand how to do this.

Alternatively, use [this hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56908350/681865), which forces the plugin to write to a file and then hand compile that file by running nvcc yourself.